# Dynamic Template Name in URL

Tags: categories, url, query

On a single entry page, I want to display a list of categories an entry is assigned to, and these categories should link back to their respective pages. Now those categories are attached to different templates so I need to display the template name dynamically for each category (finance, corporate, real-estate, etc.)

I created this query:

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT template_name FROM exp_templates WHERE template_id = ‘{template_group}’”}{template_name}{/exp:query}
```

but unfortunately it still doesn’t display my template name.

To give you an idea, if I use this query:

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT group_name FROM exp_category_groups WHERE group_id = '{category_group}’”}{group_name}{/exp:query}
```

Then the group name shows correctly (Finance, Corporate, Real Estate, etc.), but I don’t need the group name, I need the template name!

Any suggestions to point to the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about putting the template name in a custom category field?

Comment: Could you please expand on this? I'm not sure I understand...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the separate templates really different enough to warrant being separate? Usually you could code in the logic for slightly different views within a single template - much simpler and more maintainable than duplicating lots of code.

Anyway, assuming you want to keep them as separate templates, I can think of 3 options:

1. As suggested by @AllInOne, specify which template should be used via a [custom category field](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/cp/channel/cat/field/index.html)
2. Use a naming convention ensuring that your `category_url_title`s match your template group names
3. Use something like [Template Routes](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/urls/template_routes.html) (or third party [Resource Router](https://github.com/rsanchez/resource_router) is even better!) to route certain URI requests to the right template.

Like I said, my personal preference would be to re-arrange things so that just a single dynamic template is used instead of lots of different ones, but it really depends how different they are from each other. (You would then feed that single template with a category name and take different actions depending on that).

Comment: 1) and 2) aren't really applicable because Custom category fields and Category URL Titles don't apply to Category Groups.

Comment: Now every time I hit Enter my comment goes live sorry! Anyway I am already using Resource Router but I can't get it to work properly for this specific problem I'm having. Thanks @AllInOne and James Smith for your help anyway!

Comment: Actually just went ahead and used Custom Category Fields... and it works! Thanks both for your help!

Comment: It didn't actually work as I can only use one Custom Category Field per Category Group so back to square one... but thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: @lando why are the industry sectors in different category groups?

Comment: I have 5 different category groups: Finance, Corporate, Real Estate, Dispute, Industry Sectors. They all have their respective categories and they all have their own unique templates (I don't know how to create one single template to show them all dynamically). I have single entries that are categorised and I need to list and link back to all categories associated with those entries (grouped within the Category Groups above) so in the links one of the URL segments needs to be the template associated with the Category Groups ("finance", "corporate", etc.). Hope it makes sense...

Comment: Semantically, it sounds like those should not be category groups as they are all the same type of thing. Are you aware that you can nest categories in a parent-child hierarchy? Having them all in the same group would then allow you to use a naming convention.

Comment: I see what you mean, it makes sense, no I wasn't aware of the parent/child hierarchy, will give that a go and report back! thanks for the tip!

Comment: it worked in the end... added parent categories and used those instead of category groups... it never occurred to me to use parent categories, I do that all the time in WP but never done it before in EE... thanks so much for your help @JamesSmith